# How can i pass generic from function to useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to pass generic which i get from function to useState, because its a part of state. How can i do this?

Example code:

```
import React, { useState }  from "react";

const DialogContext = React.createContext<TContext>({});

type TStatus = 'close' | 'success' | 'cancel'

type TReturnContext<V> = {
  status: TStatus,
  values: V
};

type TContext = {
  open?: TOpenCallback
};

type TInstances = {
  instanceName: string
};


type TProps = {
  Layout: React.ElementType
  config: {
    [instanceName: string]: React.FC<null>
  }
};

type TOpenCallback = <T, V>(instanceName: string, params: T) => Promise<Readonly<TReturnContext<V>>>;

export const Provider: React.FC<TProps> = ({ children, Layout, config }) => {
  const [instances, setInstances] = useState<Array<TInstances>>([]);

  const open: TOpenCallback = (instanceName, params) =>
    new Promise(() => {
      setInstances(prevInstances => [
        ...prevInstances,
        { instanceName, params }
      ]);
    });

  const context = {
    open
  };


  const component = instances.map(({ instanceName, params }) => (
    <Layout
      key={instanceName}
      instanceName={instanceName}
      component={config[instanceName]}
      // cancel={cancel}
      // success={success}
      // close={close}
      params={params}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <DialogContext.Provider value={context}>
      <>
        {children}
        {component}
      </>
    </DialogContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TonCa.png)

Type 'TInstances' has no property 'params' and no string index signature

Its not full example, but when i will use open function i will know about params type, how can i pass it into useState generic?

Comment: I can't replicate that error, and the error doesn't make sense, which makes me wonder if something else is going wrong and wrongfooting the compiler. Please update the question with a [mcve] that can be copied-and-pasted into `App.tsx` of an `npx create-react-app --typescript` app to replicate the problem.

Comment: Now example is correct